# Swift argument error in making an nsarray

Tags: ios, swift

XCode 6.3.1, swift 1.2

The documentation for NSArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray says:

> func arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray(otherArray: [AnyObject]) -> [AnyObject]

Error message in compiler:

> xxx.swift:127:40: 
>   '([AnyObject]) -> [AnyObject]' is not convertible to 'NSArray'

```
func selectRowsByUUID(selectedUUIDs: [AnyObject])
{
    // use a set so we dont go all N**2
    var selectedUUIDArr2: NSArray = NSArray.arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray(selectedUUIDs!)
 ...

func selectRowsByUUID(selectedUUIDs: [AnyObject]?)
{
    var selectedUUIDArr: NSArray = NSArray.arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray(selectedUUIDs!)
 ...
```

I actually want to make an NSSet at this point, but NSArray is more familiar to most people, so I used it as an example.

```
 var selectedUUIDSet: NSSet = NSSet.setByAddingObjectsFromArray(selectedUUIDs)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `selectedUUIDs` an `NSSet` or `NSArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray()` as a *class method*, but
it is an *instance method*: It returns an array by adding objects from
one array to another array. So this would compile

```
let selectedUUIDArr = NSArray().arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray(selectedUUIDs)
```

and add the objects from `selectedUUIDs` to the empty array returned
by `NSArray()`. But the same can be achieved far easier with

```
let selectedUUIDArr = selectedUUIDs as NSArray
```

---

`setByAddingObjectsFromArray` is an instance method as well, so this
would compile

```
let selectedUUIDSet = NSSet().setByAddingObjectsFromArray(selectedUUIDs)
```

but it is easier to use the `NSSet(array:)` constructor:

```
let selectedUUIDSet = NSSet(array: selectedUUIDs)
```

---

You might also consider to use a native Swift `Set` instead,
for example

```
func selectRowsByUUID(selectedUUIDs: [NSObject])
{
    let selectedUUIDSet = Set(selectedUUIDs)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry - thought it was my swifty newbie ness, but it was a simple error.